# docker-compose build build each Dockerfile as many time as they are used

Tags: docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml with multiple services using same Dockerfile (django, celery, and many more) When I use docker-compose build, it build my container multiple times.

It make my "apply changes and restart" process costly. Is there a good way to build the Dockerfile only once? Sould I build only one container and hope it updates all?

In my case I have 5 instance of a Dockerfile simply using a different commands, different volumes…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `--build` flag along with `docker-compose up` makes docker to build all containers. If you want to build only once then you can name the image which is built in one service and for other services, instead of using dockerfile, you can use that newly built image.

```
version: '3'
services:

  wordpress-site-1:
    image: wordpress:custom
    build:
      context: ./wordpress
      dockerfile: wordpress.dockerfile
    container_name: wordpress-site-1
    links:
      - mysql-database
    depends_on:
      - mysql-database
    ports:
      - 8080:80

  wordpress-site-2:
    image: wordpress:custom
    container_name: wordpress-site-2
    links:
      - mysql-database
    depends_on:
      - mysql-database
      - wordpress-site-1
    ports:
      - 8888:80
```

Note: `build` and `image` are used in first service and only `image` is used in the second service.

This is sample usage which generates two wordpress containers, one of which  is built from the dockerfile which is specified in context and names the generated image as `wordpress:custom` and other is built from the image `wordpress:custom`. The container name is different but the image used is same in both the services. One service builds the image using build context and other uses that image. Being at safe side, you may remove any previous `wordpress:custom` image. So that wordpress-site-2 does not use cached image.

Edit 1: Extended answer to show how two containers are built using same image. Same container_name cannot be used.

Comment: Ha, I just found the flaw in my previous answer, I tested my container which run tests, which is the one having volumes over the copies, so, My answer is wrong/false. Could you extand your answer to show two services using the same container_name?

Comment: @christophe31 I have updated my answer. Same container name cannot be used but same image can be used to run different containers.

Comment: Hum, my issue is with Docker files which are not hosted but in the project… there are no images. If I can't use the same container name, how would it avoid the build to apply as many time as I have service entry with same Dockefile?

Comment: The image `wordpress:custom` is built locally by the first service. It is not hosted, but built locally by using wordpress.dockerfile (7th line in code) and this image is used in other service, here `wordpress-site-2`.

Comment: hoo, I'll try this to accept this answer if it works, it sounds neat

Comment: Thanx, it looks like working. It even shorten my docker-compose.yaml quite a bit.